# Profile Picture missing from SkyDrive Pro after theme change

Tags: sharepoint-online, branding, onedrive-for-business

I was asked to look into changing our organisation's SkyDrive Pro theme to Orange. As we were working with a developer and they weren't exactly sure how changing the theme would affect our sites they had me test it on my SkyDrive first. They had me enable "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" on my site collection features and then I was able to change the look and feel to Orange. Upon doing so, I lost my profile picture in the Skydrive and it seems that people are having a hardtime accessing my documents. I tried to switch it back but it did not work.

Normal Looking SkyDrive Pro:

[image: Normal looking SkyDrive Pro]

My SkyDrive Pro:

[image: My SkyDrive Pro]

Any ideas on how I can change it back? We've tried everything except delete my user profile. We're in a SharePoint 2013 Online environment.